# python matplotlib heatmap colorbar from transparent

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, colorbar

How to implement python matplotlib heatmap colorbar like this？

[image]

```
plt.imshow(a,aspect='auto', cmap=plt.cm.gist_rainbow_r)
plt.colorbar()
```

Comment: I think the color map which you need is not `gist_rainbow_r` but `rainbow_r`. Refer this link for more details: https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html.
Let me know if that's what you needed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This matplotlib documentation page shows some different ways to make custom colormaps, including transparency: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/index.html

In your case, it looks like you want a modified version of the gist_rainbow colormap.  You can achieve this by modifying the alpha channel as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# get colormap
ncolors = 256
color_array = plt.get_cmap('gist_rainbow')(range(ncolors))

# change alpha values
color_array[:,-1] = np.linspace(1.0,0.0,ncolors)

# create a colormap object
map_object = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name='rainbow_alpha',colors=color_array)

# register this new colormap with matplotlib
plt.colormaps.register(cmap=map_object)

# show some example data
f,ax = plt.subplots()
h = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(100,100),cmap='rainbow_alpha')
plt.colorbar(mappable=h)
```

Above code will create a colormap `rainbow_alpha` that is fully opaque at start and linearly changes transparency to be fully transparent at end. If you want a reverse effect (transparent at start and opaque at end) you can change line 9 like so:

```py
color_array[:,-1] = np.linspace(0.0,1.0,ncolors)
```

You can also change transparency of a single value:

```
 color_array[0,-1] = 0.0
```

---

*Note:* For matplotlib versions <3.7 colormaps were registered using `plt.register_cmap`

Comment: thank you!!!!I have done this work
############
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# get colormap
ncolors = 256
color_array = plt.get_cmap('gist_rainbow_r')(range(ncolors))

# change alpha values
color_array[:,-1] = np.linspace(0.0,1.0,ncolors)

Comment: Seems like reverting `np.linspace(1.0, 0.0, ncolors) -> np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, ncolors)` is essential to make it work as was suggested in the comments by @李宏强.